# How to change the ip address for a domain from the java program itself?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing, automation

we manually do the host entries to redirect a URL to a particular IP, Is there any way to do that in the automation script itself(in JAVA)?
So it points to a particular IP without every time changing the host entries manually from the system hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BrowserMob-Proxy](https://github.com/lightbody/browsermob-proxy) to fake IP addresses on the fly. You need to add your custom domain resolver like shown here:

```java
browserMobProxy.setHostNameResolver(new NativeResolver(){
    @Override
    public Collection<InetAddress> resolve(String originalHost) {
        if("webelement.click".equals(originalHost)){
            try {
                return Arrays
                        .asList(
                                new InetAddress[]{
                                        InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1")
                                });
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return super.resolve(originalHost);
    }
});
```

In this example you override the IP for one particular domain name. In [this post](https://webelement.click/en/modify_server_ip_address_in_selenium_java_tests_with_browsermob_proxy) you can find more insight on the issue.